# Are there infinite types of figurate numbers (considering those generated only by polygons and polyhedra)?

Tags: number-theory

Mathworld (Wolfram) states:

```
A figurate number, also (but mostly in texts from the 1500 and 1600s) known as
a figural number (Simpson and Weiner 1992, p. 587), is a number that can be
represented by a regular geometrical arrangement of equally spaced points.
```

[image]

So naturally, there *are infinite figurate numbers for each type of figurate number*, as generated by their respective generating functions. Examples (from Wolfram.com):

[image]

---

But my question is,- *Are there infinite **types** of figurate numbers?*

(Consider those figurate numbers formed by only polygons and polyhedra; no other n-polytopes.)

---

Is it a simple yes, because there are an infinite amount of polygon/polyhedra, therefore making number of types of figurate numbers infinite themselves? Or is there a condition binding these numbers to only be generated by only certain finite polygons/polyhedra?

Whatever the reasons are, I would appreciate it if someone tell me the answer in a somewhat rigorous manner.

---

*Auxilliary question: Are there any other esoteric (rare) figurate numbers' generating functions you've come across? Or know a database of such generating functions?*

---

Comment: Looks interesting, but I don't understand the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Looks like there are infinite types of figurate numbers...

---

[image]

[image]

*Where V is the number of 0 dimensional elements (vertices, therefore sides) and the (n) is the n-dimensional regular convex polytope number.*

---

One look at the two formulae above tells you enough; there are an infinite number of types of polygons and polyhedra (since number of sides/faces can keep increasing), thereby leading us to the conclusion there *are infinite **types** of figurate numbers*.

---

Also, a good database of these numbers: http://oeis.org/wiki/Figurate_numbers#cite_note-9